# Page Transition with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I really need your help. I am creating a page transition like this one: 
http://goo.gl/74K2rQ

But I am following this animation to my OWN design: http://goo.gl/NVjcZ2

So far what here's what I have experimented: https://jsfiddle.net/f7xpe0fo/1/

And it doesn't follow my design yet. To see my actual JSFIDDLE check it here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8y801eqh/11/

What my HTML contains is that I created two divs with ID's main-page and next-page. The first page is color red and the next page is color green. By default i hide the next-page div. Check out my HTML:

```
<div id="main-page">
 <div>
     <h1>Page Transition</h1>
       <a href="#"> Click Here</a>
</div>

</div>


<div id="next-page">
 <div>
     <h1>This is the 2nd page</h1>
       <a href="#"> Click Here</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Now for my CSS I fix their design to match up the whole page:

```
#main-page {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
 padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}

h1{
   font-family: Helvetica;
   color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;

}

#next-page{
      height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #27ae60;
 padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    display: none;
}



a{
 font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Based on my experiment here: https://jsfiddle.net/f7xpe0fo/1/

When I click on the word click here which is a link it must wrap the page to the next page and follow exactly this design: http://goo.gl/NVjcZ2

I tried to transitioned the first phase of the animation however I don't know how to proceed to the next one. I understand that I need to use jQuery on this one but how can I? Can anyone help.

Here's the JSFIDDLE of my own: https://jsfiddle.net/8y801eqh/11/

Comment: [smoothState.js](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js) might interest you.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/8y801eqh/18/ I used you html and modified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So found your solution, check it out here: http://transitiontest.comeze.com/

test1 = half page, test2 = full page, test3 = single page

In this example, there are two main objects: `#main-page` and `#next-page`, both share the same default properties except for their background color:`

```
height: 25px;
width: 375px;
position: absolute;
top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
margin: auto;
background-color: #27ae60;
display: none;
```

I use `position: absolute;` and the margins to center the object. To hide it I set `display` to `none;`.

On page load, I first reset all the properties of the main object and fade it in as you can see below.

When `.linkmain` or `.linknext` gets clicked on, they both execute the same function but for a different object (main or next).

The function first fades out the text in the main object and makes this object shrink. After both of these are finished, the object rotates using a function to transition rotation.

After all of this is finished, the function fades out the object click on, to show the new object.

Next step, showing the new object:

Again, first I reset all the properties of the object and make it fade in.

Next, I change the background color of the object matching the one of the new object.

After this is finished, I animate the height, afther that the width, and at last fade in the content of the new object.

**JS**

```
// This function is used to transition rotation
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
  var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
  var step = args.step;
  return this.each(function(i, e) {
    args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
    args.step = function(now) {
      $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
    };

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
  });
};

// Set all properties of main object to default and fade it in
$("#main-page").css("background-color", "#e74c3c");
$("#main-page").css("height", "100vh");
$("#main-page").css("width", "100%");
$("#main-page").fadeIn();
$(".maincontent").fadeIn();

// This gets activated once clicked on object .linkmain
$(".linkmain").on("click", function() {
    $(".maincontent").fadeOut();
    $("#main-page").animate({
        width: "25px",
        height: "375px"
    }, function() {
        $(this).animateRotate(90);
    });

    // Hide the main object after all the animations above are finished
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#main-page").fadeOut();       
    }, 1500);

    // Fade in the new page after all the animations above are finished
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#next-page").animateRotate(0, 0);
        $("#next-page").css("height", "25px");
        $("#next-page").css("width", "375px");
        $("#next-page").fadeIn();
        $("#next-page").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#27ae60"
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                height: "100vh"
            }, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    width: $("body").width()
                }, function() {
                    $(".nextcontent").fadeIn(300);
                });
            });
        });
    }, 800);
});

// This gets activated once clicked on object .linknext 
$(".linknext").on("click", function() {
    $(".nextcontent").fadeOut();
    $("#next-page").animate({
        width: "25px",
        height: "375px"
    }, function() {
        $(this).animateRotate(-90);
    });

    // Hide the next object after all the animations above are finished
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#next-page").fadeOut();          
    }, 1500);

    // Fade in the main page after all the animations above are finished
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#main-page").animateRotate(0, 0);
    $("#main-page").css("height", "25px");
    $("#main-page").css("width", "375px");
        $("#main-page").fadeIn();
        $("#main-page").animate({
            height: "100vh"
        }, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: $("body").width()
            }, function() {
                $(".maincontent").fadeIn(300);
            });
        });
    }, 1400);
});
```

Comment: Almost close enough. How can I apply this to my current JSFIDDLE?

Comment: I was referring to this one: https://jsfiddle.net/8y801eqh/11/ . The When the "Click here" button was click it must animate the whole page to that animation.

Comment: Also when you click back on the "Next Page" It will reverse the animation back to the first page?

Comment: Just one last edit mate. Is it possible to make it a full page? And then rectangular bar will be centered?

Comment: @Kimberly Wright: Yeah I agree. Is it possible to make it a ful page? and then the rectangular bar will centered as well.

Comment: Awesome mate! Thanks! BTW. Did you use two files? is it possible to do just it in just one file? like index.html file.

Comment: Hmm..How to prevent the 1st transition to pop-up during the loading or the beginning of the page? If you would refresh the page it automatically pops-out.

Comment: Yeah. BTW mate can you explain your codes? Sorry Beginner here. :) I appreciate.

Comment: Fixed in test3, try that one again. I'll edit my post to provide explanation.

Comment: Do the comments provide a better explanation?

Comment: Please just edit it and provide some explanation how the codes work. :)

Comment: Does this provide enough explanation?

Comment: @TheOnlyError: I tried to save this to my local computer and while transitioning here's what I get: http://prntscr.com/7gpql1 how can I fix this? I copied the same files on test3.

Comment: I think it'd be better to continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80502/page-transition).

Comment: @TheOnlyError: I just put comments on the chat. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Basic concept:

1. Play the first animation and use [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function to get the content of the requested page.
2. When the animation has ended and you got response from the server in `.done` function, extract the content of the main div from the response, replace it with the current content and play the second animation.
3. Modify the url, headers and history.

You can play your animation by setting up properties of a class and then adding it to the div by [addclass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function.

There may be a problem when different pages uses different js scripts, though.

There are also scripts that can automate this things, but im not familiar with any, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actual answer, but may be this code will helpful for you:

```js
$('.clickbutton').click(function(){
    $('.mainWrap').addClass('animate');
     setTimeout(function() {
         /* Code to show the page , now this is dummy code*/
        $('#main-page, #next-page').toggle();
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.mainWrap').removeClass('animate');
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#main-page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
}

h1{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

#next-page{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #27ae60;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    display:none;
}

a{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    
    
}

.mainWrap:before, .mainWrap:after {
    background-color:yellow;
    display: block;
    
    content: '';
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0.4s;
}

.animate.mainWrap:before, .animate.mainWrap:after
{
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0s;   
}

.mainWrap::before {
  top: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.mainWrap::after {
  bottom: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainWrap">
    <div id="main-page">
        <div>
            <h1>Page Transition</h1>
            <a class="clickbutton" href="javascript:void(0)"> Click Here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="next-page">
        <div>
            <h1>This is the 2nd page</h1>
            <a class="clickbutton" href="javascript:void(0)"> Click Here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added in fiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/8y801eqh/15/)

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hecifu/6/edit)***

- Use CSS3 animation with keyframes.
- Use a HTML overlay element that covers the screen
- Use jQuery to trigger a CSS class that is bound to the mentioned CSS3 animation.
- While CSS3 animates the fancy overlay, fadeToggle your pages!

HTML:

```
<div class="page" id="page1">
    <h1>PAGE 1</h1>
    <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page2">
    <h1>PAGE 2</h1>
    <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>


<div id="overlay"></div> <!-- we'll animate this guy here -->
```

CSS:

```
h1{   
  font: 60px/2 Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
.page{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:  90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  top:  5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  color: white;
}
#page1{
  background: #008562;
}
#page2{
  display: none;
  background: #ff8600;
}
.page a{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#overlay{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
  width:  100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px #fff;
}

#overlay.overlayAnimation{
  visibility: visible;
  animation: overlayAnimation 4s forwards;
}
@keyframes overlayAnimation {
  0% {
    width:  100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
    background: transparent;
  }
  25%{
    width:  10px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: translate3d(calc(50vw - 5px), calc(50vh - 100px), 0);
  }
  50%{
    width:  10px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: translate3d(calc(50vw - 5px), calc(50vh - 100px), 0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50.1%{
    width:  200px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: translate3d(calc(50vw - 100px), calc(50vh - 5px), 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  75%{
    width:  200px;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate3d(calc(50vw - 100px), 0px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    width:  100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0) rotate(0deg);
    visibility:hidden;
  }
}
```

And a bit of jQuery to trigger the CSS3 overlayAnimation class:

```
var $pages = $(".page");
var $overlay = $("#overlay");

$('.page a').on("click", function(){
  if($overlay.hasClass("overlayAnimation")) return;
  $pages.fadeToggle(4000);
  $overlay.addClass("overlayAnimation").on("animationend", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("overlayAnimation");
  });
});
```

Comment: How can you fade the text? It looks awful if you will just make it bounce like that. Also will it reverse back the animation when you click the "Click here" button on the 2nd page?

Comment: @KimberlyWright nothing bounces here. What old browser do you use? Have you tried the demo? Yes, as yo ucan clearly see you can click on the second page. You have a demo, play, try. you know.

Comment: @KimberlyWright currently the pages fade one-into-other, to prevent the text to be visible you can simply add into the transition the desired background color. For the reverse, in that case you'd have to create another set of transitions and change a bit tje jQuery. Waiting for OP's comments in any case.

Comment: Hi yes, How can you fade the text? It looks awful if you will just make it bounce like that. Also will it reverse back the animation when you click the "Click here" button on the 2nd page?

Comment: @SamNorton As I've said. you can "fade the text" by actually applying a background color into the CSS3 animation keyframes. Nothing bounces. what browser you use?

Comment: I am using firefox, chrome and safari. Can you show an example?

Comment: @sam Can you see the JSBin Demo link at the very beginning of my answer?